# Windows default font in bars?

Tags: windows-8, fonts

I want to know what's the Windows default font name used in bars. I can't find the window to change window color and appearance in the Windows 8, and it'd show the current font name in the bar (I believe).

The font is used in this bar:

[image: Navigation bar]

Comment: It's [Segoe UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#Segoe_UI).

Answer (score 2):

Segoe UI as far as i know! but the fonts may vary depending on what window you have open.

Comment: So, Segoe Ui is a little different between the font in the bar when compared in graphics (pixels)... it's almost there.